# How can I display a form (from Twig render), when I click on btn

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

Right now, I try to use FosUserBundle in my Application...

I want to integrate the login form, in my view when I click on the login button.

How to use twig method like :

```
{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}
```

with a jquery click() events?

Exemple:

**layout.html.twig** (when I have not clicked on the login button)

```
<html>
  <header>...</header>     
  <body>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
  </body>
  <footer>...</footer>
</html>
```

**layout.html.twig** (when I have clicked on the login button)

```
<html>
  <header>...</header>     
  <body>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
  </body>
  <footer>...</footer>
<!--{% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}-->
  <div id="login">  
    <form>
        <input></input>
        <input></input>
        <input></input>
   </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

I want Mix

```
   var = {% render url('fos_user_security_login') %}
```

with

```
  $( "#login" ).append( var )...
```

something like this...

Thanks U!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you should put the content in the page from the beginning, hidden, and show it after click on link.

But if you want to add it dynamically, you could use a prototype:

In your login button put a property

```
data-prototype="{{ _self.login_form_prototype()|e }}"
```

Somewhere, outside of other blocks, implement the prototype:

```
{% macro login_form_prototype() %}
    <form>
        <input></input>
        <input></input>
        <input></input>
   </form>
{% endmacro %}
```

In Javascript, use this on click event:

```
var prototype = $('#login-btn').data('prototype');
$( "#login" ).html( prototype );
```

If you have the login form as a variable, you can send it as a parameter to the macro.

Hope I understood what you wanted to do.

Comment: In fact, it's ok now...Thanks U!